# How to merge / combine list of tuples of diffrent sizes

Tags: scala

I have following two lists-

```
List(("ABC",1,10),("PQR",1,10))
List((1,"abc",3940903,0.0),(2,"pqr",1234,3.0))
```

I want following output

```
List(("ABC",1,10,1,"abc",3940903,0.0),("PQR",1,10,2,"pqr",1234,3.0)
```

I tried out concat, ::: but didn't worked for me.

How do I get above output using scala??

Answer (score 5):

You can not merge tuples directly in Scala. There are two ways to achieve it

Using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples)

```
val A = List(("ABC", 1, 10), ("PQR", 1, 10))   
val B = List((1, "abc", 3940903, 0.0), (2, "pqr", 1234, 3.0))
val zippedList = A zip B 
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._
zippedList.map { case (a, b) => a ++ b } 
//List((ABC,1,10,1,abc,3940903,0.0), (PQR,1,10,2,pqr,1234,3.0))
```

This method works on arbitrary size tuples

Using no external library

```
zippedList.map { case ((a,b,c), (p,q,r,s)) => (a,b,c,p,q,r,s) }
//List((ABC,1,10,1,abc,3940903,0.0), (PQR,1,10,2,pqr,1234,3.0))
```

The tuples should have fixed arity for this to work

Comment: What is max. arity for tuples? Is it 22 ?